# How does TypeScript knows the type of other modules integrated as dependency?

Tags: typescript, module

If a TS module (converted to JS on publish) is npm installed within my TS app, how does TypeScript know the types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A module written in Typescript is separately compiled to a `.js` file and a `.ts.d` file.  The `.js` file contains only the application logic, where the `.ts.d` file contains the type definitions.  This allows you to separately import the logic from the typings, which decreases the size of the published binary version of a package.

Most major packages have separate type definitions packages which can be installed on NPM via `npm install --save-dev @types/<package_name>`.  You can find a listing of these [here](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/).